# Delphi FMX: How to write a custom shader filter?

Tags: delphi, directx, firemonkey, hlsl

In Delphi 10.2. using Firemonkey for a Windows 10 desktop application I would like to understand the internal calculation of `TRippleFilter` and adapt it to my needs.

In the unit `FMX.Filter.Standard` in `constructor TRippleFilter.Create` I can see the resulting shader code for DirectX. To understand `TRippleFilter` and learn how to create a similar custom filter I am looking for the corresponding HLSL source code.

I have already searched the internet intensively but unfortunately have not found anything.

Where could I find the source code or where could I find more resources to learn how to create my own shader filters?